# Lazy loading variable error

Tags: swift, core-data, computed-properties

I am writing a program that involves core data. I created a class variable for my *context* and *entity*  and have my code written like this:

```
class PersistencyManager {

    var context : NSManagedObjectContext{
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let localContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        return localContext
    }
    var userEntity : NSEntityDescription {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(EntityNames.User, inManagedObjectContext: context)
        return entity!

    }  
    struct EntityNames {
        private static let User = "User"
        private static let Category = "Category"
    }
}
```

Everything so far works fine, But what I want to do is to "*lazy*"ly load userEntity

Like this :

```
   lazy var userEntity : NSEntityDescription = {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(EntityNames.User, inManagedObjectContext: context)
        return entity!

    }()
```

But when I do, I get an error: ***"Instance member 'context' cannot be used on type 'Persistency Manager' "***

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(EntityNames.User, inManagedObjectContext: self.context)`

Note I'm using `self.context` instead of just `context`. This builds for me in a playground.

Comment: The `= {...}()` syntax is used to define (and then execute) a block of code for, in this case, a complex initialization sequence.

Comment: @DavidBerry Thanks, you're right - was thinking of a different problem. Updated my answer.

Comment: Got it now I think.  The issue is that the anonymous code block doesn't automatically get access to instance variables without specifying self, not that the error message gives any clue to that.

Comment: Right - the instance variable wasn't being captured within the scope of the closure.

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem. It all make sense now.